# Android firestore exception in update statement

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently am working on a health application which stores sensor readings..
Am trying to store sensor data like the following tree [Sensor Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IppTv.png)

So at the beginning, when i create a user i add my info in ease then i add two empty hashmaps for storing sensor readings and time

[User creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpn29.png)

Then when i have some data i try to store them for the user with specified UID
[Doing update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PICG7.png)

But there is an exception occurs:
**W/System.err: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/0rAK1hmSjOgHluFyRulwjlNt2qu2**

So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does the document with the id seen in error message exists in your database? Also please refrain from posting your project id on public resources.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, it can't find your document. I suggest you check if your **uid** is **not null** and if the document **exists** before updating. Furthermore, in your code you are defining that if the shared pref uid is not found to be set **default to null**, which later on can result on this error (because not document with null uid can exist).

On any future question you have, please post it the correct way. For example, post your code with the code option on the editor and not as screenshot.